# Passing column names to Pandas read_csv() function

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file that looks as follows:

```
,time,o,h,l,c
0,2021-03-17 09:30:00,101.25,103.98,90.17,101.78
1,2021-03-17 09:45:00,102.83,107.49,95.22,101.93
2,2021-03-17 10:00:00,100.92,102.90,97.19,102.80
```

I'm reading in this data using the `read_csv` function, as follows:

```
cols = ['indx', 'timestamp', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close']
df = pd.read_csv('prices.csv', names=cols)
```

The resulting dataframe looks as follows:

```
    Unnamed: 0  time                o       h       l       c
0   0           2021-03-17 09:30:00 101.25  103.98  90.17   101.78
1   1           2021-03-17 09:45:00 102.83  107.49  95.22   101.93
2   2           2021-03-17 10:00:00 100.92  102.90  97.19   102.80
```

Passing the `names` parameter seems to have *no effect* on the column names.

**EDIT**:

Passing the `header` parameter (per the docs) results in the same behavior:

```
cols = ['indx', 'timestamp', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close']
df = pd.read_csv('prices.csv', header=0, names=cols)
```

Do I have to pass *another* parameter to the `read_csv` function to customize the column names?

Thanks!

Comment: Will you please show a sample of your raw CSV file, including the header and some rows?

Comment: From [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) (emphasis mine): "names: List of column names to use. _If the file contains a header row, then you should explicitly pass header=0 to override the column names._ Duplicates in this list are not allowed."

Comment: @richardec -- I edited the original question.

Comment: @G.Anderson -- passing the `header` parameter results in the same behavior.

Comment: That can't be your original CSV file. It's not a CSV file at all—there are no commas in it. @equinimity this question is hard to understand. Will you please provide exactly the data and code you're using?

Comment: @richardec -- edited the original question.  Notice the leading comma in the header row (which might be causal).

Comment: Did you try my answer? Using your CSV file the code worked for me. (Note that there is no comma between `l` and `c` in your sample, which is probably a typo.)

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce, the given file produced the intended result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that you need to pass `header=0` to `read_csv`:

```
df = pd.read_csv('prices.csv', names=cols, header=0)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   indx            timestamp    open    high    low   close
0     0  2021-03-17 09:30:00  101.25  103.98  90.17  101.78
1     1  2021-03-17 09:45:00  102.83  107.49  95.22  101.93
2     2  2021-03-17 10:00:00  100.92  102.90  97.19  102.80
```

Comment: While the docs say `explicitly pass header=0`, I think they really mean `pass header=[actual header row number]`. This allows you to still skip any text above the header, while still replacing the header column names with the desired ones.